# Cant' delete SelectedItem from TreeView binded to XML

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I'm binded my TreeView ItemsSource to XmlDocument via XmlDataProvider.

xaml:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData" XPath="/root" />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        ...
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    ...
 </Window.Resources>
 <GroupBox Header="XMLTree" DataContext="{StaticResource XmlData}">
        <TreeView Name="TemplateTree"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" KeyDown="TemplateTree_KeyDown" />
 </GroupBox>
```

code behind:

```
    private void LoadTemplateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "XML" + " (*.xml)|*.xml";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() != true) return;

            Document = new XmlDocument();
            Document.Load(ofd.FileName);
            Provider = (XmlDataProvider) FindResource("XmlData");
            Provider.Document = Document;
            Provider.Source = new Uri(ofd.FileName);
            Provider.Refresh();
    }
```

When I edit some info inside my tree or add new nodes, I can easily save data and refresh the tree. But when I try to delete the branch with this function

```
    private void TemplateTree_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
            {
                TemplateTree.Items.Remove(TemplateTree.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I get an error: `Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.`

So, how to make it properly remove items from tree and from XmlDocument?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to manipulate the ItemsSource like the error states. So u could store the xml file in a variable first, and then bind it to the itemssource. Then you can manipulate the xml file variable and refresh the itemssource.

Comment: Can you explain this? My xml doc is stored in XmlDocument variable. What can I do with that to find and remove the correct node, when event sender is the tree?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, did not know that `Items` collection of `TreeView` contains objects of the binded type. Getting those objects as `XmlElement` made removal pretty easy operation. Just deleted `SelectedItem` from `Provider.Document`.